# RegionPlot example in documentation fails

Tags: plotting, bugs, regions

**Bug introduced in 10.4 and fixed in 11.0**

---

I am running *Mathematica* 10.4.1.0 on a MacBook Pro OSX 10.11.5. I opened the documentation for [`TransformedRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion.html), went to this example in **Scope** > **Formula Regions**. When I open this particular documentation, the image is present, but when I ran these two lines:

```
pr = ParametricRegion[{Sin[θ], Sin[2 θ]}, {{θ, 0, 2 π}}]
RegionPlot[pr]
```

I got a blank image:

[image]

I've tried quitting the kernel and I've tried restarting `Mathematica`, but it still doesn't work.

Anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: Yep, same here on Windows. Also the first basic example for `ParametricRegion` fails.

Comment: I seem to have the same problem.  The example given in Mathematica help `ParametricRegion[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {{t, 0, 2 Pi}}]]` also fails (Mathematica 10.4.1, 64-bit Linux)

Comment: Curiously it works if I replace 2 Pi with 6.28

Comment: OK. I'll report this to Wolfram.

Comment: and works with 1.9999999 Pi ...

Comment: Related question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/113126/3066

Comment: On 10.4 it works for pi but not 2 pi Also, works for (100 / 49 ) pi.

Comment: Very odd - works on 10.3.1 but fails later versions.  @Young - but then it fails with `1.99999999 π`

Comment: works with 2 pi on 10.2.0

Answer (score 1):

As noted, this is fixed. Here it is on 11.0.1.

[image]